# linking layout.pug file from layouts folder

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So I am clearing up the structure from a project and I have the layouts, navigation and footer in a separate folder.

I am now trying to render the layouts file in my files, but I can't seem to get the path right.

Here is the structure

[image: image #1]

in the dashboard/index I have tried

`extends ../layout`,
`extends ./layout` &
`extends ../../layout`

Here is the layouts.pug file

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    meta(charset='utf-8')

    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/output.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css')
  body(class='antialiased min-h-screen')
    include navigation
    include error
    block content
    include footer

    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/fontawesome-all.min.js' defer)
    script(src='/javascripts/site.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to `extend` a file from another folder, you have to write out the full path. The way you're writing your `extends` statement only references the folder, not the file I believe you are trying to target.

```
extends ./../layout/layout.pug
```

Comment: `GET /dashboard 500 13.033 ms - 0` https://gyazo.com/ec910eafccc60319b31f15a894548c61

Comment: I mean, what's the error that appears in your developer console?

Comment: Oh sorry, here we go https://gyazo.com/f9ffa4dbe23ed5e8430aa77fd17c9851

Comment: I just invited you to a chat room. Please join it at your convenience. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/165849/pug-help-chat?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by doing

```
extends ../layouts/layout
```

for files inside of folders i.e.`dashboard/index.pug` and

```
extends ./layouts/layout
```

for files inside of the views directory i.e. `login.pug`.

Answer (score 0):

in order to set file address do this `include /../component/file` in pug file
and if you using pug separately in render function path these options:

```js
 pug.render(pugTemplate, {
      filename: 'Pug', // in order to use relative address (your case)
      basedir: __dirname, // absolute address
      // other options
    })
```